# Matching game in C

Tags: c, matrix, matching

SO FAR: Hey everyone! I updated my game so that both card choices print in the new matrix! But now, the first matrix ( will all [$] showing) isn't printing. Also, there is an extra [$] card printing. My code thus far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stdio.h" // stdio.h significa cabecera de entrada y salida estándar

void imprimeGrid(char (*card)[4])
{
    int f,c;
    printf("     1    2    3    4\n");
    for (f = 0; f<4; f++) // para controlar el numero de filas
    {
        printf(" %i ",f+1); // para imprimir el numero de las columnas, hacer f+1
        for (c=0; c<4; c++)
        {
            printf(" [$] ",card[f][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void juego() 
{
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    char card[4][4];
    printf ("El primer NIVEL: \n\n");
    card[0][0]='H';
    card[0][1]='O';
    card[0][2]='C';
    card[0][3]='O';
    card[1][0]='f';
    card[1][1]='H';
    card[1][2]='C';
    card[1][3]='H';
    card[2][0]='H';
    card[2][1]='C';
    card[2][2]='f';
    card[2][3]='O';
    card[3][0]='f';
    card[3][1]='C';
    card[3][2]='H';
    card[3][3]='f';

    printf("Tarjeta 1) Ingrese numero de fila: ");
    scanf("%i",&x1);
    printf("Ingrese numero de columna: ");
    scanf("%i",&y1);
    x1=x1-1;
    y1=y1-1;

    printf ("Su eleccion es:[%c]",card[x1][y1]);
    fflush (stdin);
    printf("\n \n");
    printf("Tarjeta 2) Ingrese numero de fila: ");
    scanf("%i",&x2);
    printf("Ingrese numero de columna: ");
    scanf("%i",&y2);
    x2=x2-1;
    y2=y2-1;
    printf ("Su eleccion es:[%c]",card[x2][y2]);
    printf("\n \n");

    int f,c;
    printf("     1    2    3    4\n");
    for (f = 0; f<4; f++)
    {
    printf(" %i ",f+1);
        for (c=0; c<4; c++)
        {
            if ((f==x1) && (c==y1))
            {
                printf(" [%c] ",card[f][c]);
            }
            if ((f==x2) && (c==y2))
            {
                printf(" [%c] ",card[f][c]);
            }
            else
           {
               printf(" [$] ");
           }
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    if (card[x1][y1]==card[x2][y2])
    {
        printf("Tienes una pareja!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No tienes una pareja!\n");
    }

}

void main() 
{
    int again = 0;
    do 
    {
        juego();
        printf("Enter 1 to play again. Enter 0 to quit. ");
        scanf("%i",&again);
    } while(again);
}
```

Comment: You should really tell us more about it. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: what is the `[@]` in your printf's?

Comment: No entiendo español (I do not understand Spanish.) :(

Comment: also, `c`  is not initialized when `if(c=1)` evaluates.

Comment: and `nombre` is never used

Comment: and x2/y2 are decreased before initialized.

Comment: Why is there a change from card[f][c] to card[f][0]? Also, [@] is just the design of the game card. What I don't know how to do is: the person picks two cards, but how to I print their selections/make the changes to the matrix so that only those two "cards" show H/O/f/C? How do I keep them that way if they are equal, and how do I change the matrix to all [@] if they aren't equal? And thank you for organizing my program! Thanks to all that commented as well!

Comment: thanks @eznme! the game is basically a chemistry related game where the player selects two cards out of 16 [@] cards. If they are equal (2 H, 2 O,2 f or 2 C), they should stay revealed. If not, they turn back to [@]. I'm having a problem with changing a card after it is selected in the matrix, and reverting back to the original gameboard if the two cards aren't the same.

Comment: @eznme - also, the program should do the opposite of what you did. All the elements should be hidden and shown as [@], except for the two selected. I changed this part:                           printf(" %i [$] ",f+1, card[f][0]);
        int c; for (c=1; c<4; c++)
        { printf([$]",card[f][c]);                                                                         and this part:
    card[x1][y1] =("[%c]");
    card[x2[y2]=([%c]");                                                              but it isnt working quite right. I want to print the two selected cards in the new matrix.

Comment: @user3053042 I changed my answer. I hope it now does what you want.

Comment: @eznme, thanks a lot!! its getting me closer to what I wanted! The last thing (hopefully) that I want to ask is how to print card(x1,y1) and card (x2,y2) in the same matrix? and how do int rShow and int cShow work? how does the program consider when c==cShow and f==rShow?

Comment: @eznme : would it be along the lines of     imprimeGrid(card,x1,y1,card,x2,y2); so that both cards appear on the same matrix?

Comment: @user3053042 yes you could do that. you can write `printGrid(card, int cShow1, int rShow1, int cShow2, int rShow2) {...}` and inside: `if( (c==cShow1 && f==rShow1) || (c==cShow2 && f==rShow2) ) {...}`.

Comment: @eznme - now im able to print both card options on the same matrix, but there is an extra "card "[$]" printing after the second card is selected. How do i fix that? my latest program is up! and thank you for taking your time to help!

Comment: @user3053042 sure. you changed it in a different way. try it the way I wrote first please.

Comment: @eznme when I used the program you provided below, the first card printed just fine, but the second didn't print for me - and there were two different matrices as a result instead if printing in the same one. But your program did provide help in how to print the result in the matrix.

Comment: @user3053042 I now changed the answer to do that.

Comment: @eznme thanks!!! last question: lets say the cards are equal, so they don't have to flip back to [$]. what do I do so that when the player choices two new cards, they also print in that same matrix?

Comment: @eznme, also why imprimeGrid(card,-1,-1,-1,-1)? why the -1?

Comment: @user3053042 ok I will change my answer so that what was clear stays clear. the `-1` is so that the `if(...)` are always false, so that it prints [@] for every cell.

Comment: @user3053042 i changed my answer so that what is visible stays visible.

Comment: @eznme thanks soooo much for your patience and help. May you be successful!!!!

Comment: @user3053042 sure. dont forget to accept my answer if your question is finished. good luck to you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only printing the grid once. You probably want to make a change to the grid and then print it again. I also fixed 6 little mistakes.

Update 3: changed to fit the new requirements

here's the new output:

```
El primer NIVEL:

    1    2    3    4
 1  [@]  [@]  [@]  [@]
 2  [@]  [@]  [@]  [@]
 3  [@]  [@]  [@]  [@]
 4  [@]  [@]  [@]  [@]
Primera Posicion X (fila): 2
Primera Posicion Y (columna): 3
Su eleccion es:[C]

Segunda Posicion X: 3
Segunda Posicion Y: 4
Su eleccion es:[H]

    1    2    3    4
 1  [@]  [@]  [@]  [@]
 2  [@]  [@]  [@]  [@]
 3  [@]  [C]  [@]  [@]
 4  [@]  [@]  [H]  [@]
Enter 1 to play again. Enter 0 to quit. 1
Primera Posicion X (fila): 1
Primera Posicion Y (columna): 1
Su eleccion es:[H]

Segunda Posicion X: 2
Segunda Posicion Y: 2
Su eleccion es:[f]

    1    2    3    4
 1  [H]  [@]  [@]  [@]
 2  [@]  [f]  [@]  [@]
 3  [@]  [C]  [@]  [@]                       <- keep visible
 4  [@]  [@]  [H]  [@]
Enter 1 to play again. Enter 0 to quit.
```

the code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
void printGrid(char (*selected)[4], char (*card)[4]) {
    printf("    1    2    3    4\n");
    int f; for (f = 0; f<4; f++) // para controlar el numero de filas
    {
        printf(" %i ",f+1); // para imprimir el numero de las columnas, hacer f+1
        int c; for (c=0; c<4; c++)
        {
            if( selected[f][c] ) {
                printf(" [%c] ",card[f][c]);
            } else {
                printf(" [@] ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void juego(char (*selected)[4], char (*card)[4])
{
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;

    printf("Primera Posicion X (fila): ");
    scanf("%i",&x1);
    printf("Primera Posicion Y (columna): ");
    scanf("%i",&y1);
    x1=x1-1;
    y1=y1-1;

    selected[y1][x1] = 1;

    printf ("Su eleccion es:[%c]",card[x1][y1]);
    fflush (stdin);
    printf("\n \n");
    printf("Segunda Posicion X: ");
    scanf("%i",&x2);
    printf("Segunda Posicion Y: ");
    scanf("%i",&y2);
    x2=x2-1;
    y2=y2-1;
    printf ("Su eleccion es:[%c]",card[x2][y2]);
    printf("\n \n");

    selected[y2][x2] = 1;

    printGrid(selected, card); 
}

int main() 
{
    int again = 0;

    char card[4][4];
    printf ("El primer NIVEL: \n\n");
    card[0][0]='H';
    card[0][1]='O';
    card[0][2]='C';
    card[0][3]='O';
    card[1][0]='f';
    card[1][1]='f';
    card[1][2]='C';
    card[1][3]='H';
    card[2][0]='H';
    card[2][1]='C';
    card[2][2]='f';
    card[2][3]='H';
    card[3][0]='f';
    card[3][1]='C';
    card[3][2]='H';
    card[3][3]='O';

    char selected[4][4] = { 0 };

    printGrid(selected, card);

    do {
        juego(selected, card);
        printf("Enter 1 to play again. Enter 0 to quit. ");
        scanf("%i",&again);
    } while(again);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is there a change from card[f][c] to card[f][0]? Also, [@] is just the design of the game card. What I don't know how to do is: the person picks two cards, but how to I print their selections/make the changes to the matrix so that only those two "cards" show H/O/f/C? How do I keep them that way if they are equal, and how do I change the matrix to all  [@] if they aren't equal? And thank you for organizing my program! Thanks to all that commented as well!

Comment: ok, About the `card[f][0]`: In your version the `c` was not initialized but you used it as if it were `c=0` so I changed that. About the `[@]`: in simple terms the number of `%`'s in printf has to be the same as the number of arguments following the string. Finally how to "make the matrix all @": `int cc,rr; for(cc=0;cc<4;cc++) { for(rr=0;rr<4;rr++) { card[r][c]='@'; }}